# Swift UISwitch event before value changes

Tags: swift, events, uiswitch, uicontrol

I just wanted to check few conditions before the UISwitch value changes. If conditions are met, then only allow it to change.
In documentation, only valueChanged event is available. Which is called after the value is changed.

Any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two alternatives:

1. Make a check at some point before the switch would be toggled and disable it.
2. Let the switch be toggled and in your `valueChanged` method perform the check before proceeding. If the conditions are not met, use the `setOn()` method to reset the `UISwitch` to the previous state.

Comment: The second alternative doesn't work ok because the animation happens before you you could set it to the previous state. So it changes state and then it goes back showing it's poorly designed. Any ideas how to check just before the switch should be toggled?

Comment: Yes, i tried to set it back to previous state by `setOn()` but problem is, valueChanged event is not called when we set using `setOn()`

Comment: I'd say it looks even more poorly designed if it doesn't animate when the switch is pressed, as it appears to not respond in that case.

Comment: @87k Of course it doesn't. `setOn` is only a UI change, it doesn't send a message to the receiver.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible but could it be done by making a subclass of UISwitch and overriding it's `on` property and adding custom setter and getter?

Comment: when event is changed, few things get updated. In such case, i have to revert those changes back by calling some function. This seems bad.

Comment: @87k In that case you may want to move the `setOn` call inside the method that reverts the changes.

Comment: if we move `setOn()` inside a method, how do method know `uiswitch` value is changed?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me now. If you need to revert any changes after a switch is pressed and some conditions are not met, call the method that reverts your changes from within `valueChanged` and at the same time revert any UI changes.

Comment: Ok fine. using methods i have made it working. I feel `beforeChange` event should be provided at core level.

Comment: Well, if you really want, you could override the `touchesBegan` method on the `UISwitch` since that method gets called before `valueChanged` but then you'll receive an update for every touch, so I wouldn't really recommend it. It is designed this way for a reason, and I'd say it's worse sacrificing responsiveness instead of the app _"looking poorly designed"_ when the switch toggles on and off.

Answer (score 0):

As [@xoudini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389870/xoudini) suggested in the comments under his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39017674/7890303), the desired behaviour can be achieved by subclassing a `UISwitch` class and overriding it's `hitTest(_:with:)` and `touchesBegan(_:with:)` methods.

You override `hitTest(_:with:)` to stop event propagation to the subviews of your subclass, that way actual switch view the responds to gestures is never reached. And override `touchesBegan(_:with:)` to provide callback to act when switch has been tapped.

**NB!** You lose some native behaviours such as long-press and pan gesture interactions. Current solution limits switch to only tap gestures (however, the state change is still animated).

```swift
final class Switch: UISwitch {
    
    var onTouchesBegun: ((UISwitch) -> Void)?

    override func hitTest(
        _ point: CGPoint,
        with event: UIEvent?
    ) -> UIView? {
        guard self.point(inside: point, with: event) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard isUserInteractionEnabled else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return self
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(
        _ touches: Set<UITouch>,
        with event: UIEvent?
    ) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        
        onTouchesBegun?(self)
    }
}
```

After you instantiate your subclass, set callback from which you manually, programmatically change the state of the switch.

```swift
let isOn: Bool
let animated: Bool

let switch: Switch = .init()
switch.onTouchesBegun = { [isOn, animated] switch in
    // Execute code that determines if/when switch should change state
    
    switch.setOn(isOn, animated: animated)
}
```